# Смена метки при клике

Tags: yandex-maps-api, drupal, yandex-maps-jsapi, drupal7

Сайт на Drupal 7. Карта создана при помощи модуля Geofield Yandex Maps. Все объекты на карте выводятся с помощью geoQuery.
Нужно при клике на метку,менять цвет ( в моем случае  я меняю iconImageHref). Но при клике на другую метку,у предыдущей не меняется цвет на дефолтный. Нашел код,который все делает как надо,но он дублирует созданные объекты и отрабатывает только на них. Подскажите как сделать правильно. Вот код

```
Drupal.behaviors.addMap = {
  attach : function(context, settings) {
    (function ($) {
    $('#geofield-ymap-views-block-dilers-block-map').bind('yandexMapInit', function (event, map) {
      var myMap = Drupal.geofieldYmap.data['geofield-ymap-views-block-dilers-block-map'].map;
      var myPlacemark = Drupal.geofieldYmap.data['geofield-ymap-views-block-dilers-block-map'].map.geoObjects;
      var myBalloon = Drupal.geofieldYmap.data['geofield-ymap-views-block-dilers-block-map'].map.balloon;

 // Получаем список объектов в GeoJson
      var objects = $(this).data('map-objects');
      collection = ymaps.geoQuery(myPlacemark);
      if (collection.isReady()) {
          for (i = 0; i < collection.getLength(); i++) {
              var pm = collection.get(i);

              // Обработчик клика для метки
              pm.events.add('click', function (e) {

                  // Цвет всех меток
                  for (j = 0; j < collection.getLength(); j++) {
                      var currentPm = collection.get(j);
                      currentPm.options.set(
                          'iconImageHref', '/sites/default/files/images/map/datsun-clicked.png'
                      );
                  }

                  // Цвет текущей метки
                  e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', '/sites/default/files/images/map/datsun-icon.png');
              });

              map.geoObjects.add(pm);

          }

      }

    })(jQuery);
  }
};
```

РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
// Получаем список объектов в GeoJson
        var objects = $(this).data('map-objects');
        collection = ymaps.geoQuery(objects);
        var activePlacemark;
        myPlacemark.events.add('click', function(e){
          if (activePlacemark) {
            activePlacemark.options.set('iconImageHref', '/sites/default/files/images/map/datsun-icon.png');

          }
          activePlacemark = e.get('target');
          activePlacemark.options.set('iconImageHref', '/sites/default/files/images/map/datsun-clicked.png');

        })
```

Comment: Правильно будет сохранять ссылку на активную метку в переменной. При клике по метке проверять есть ли в этой переменной ссылка на предыдущую нажатую метку и менять у неё цвет на дефолтный. Затем присваивать ей текущую нажатую метку и присваивать ей новый цвет.

Comment: @se0ga А как получить ссылку на предыдущую метку?

Comment: Создать переменную и сохранить туда ссылку на переменную при открытии на ней балуна не получается?

Comment: @se0ga я не совсем понимаю как это сделать. ссылка на активную метку
e.get('target') ?

Comment: Вот так https://jsfiddle.net/8cf4x52a/ .

Comment: @se0ga Огромное спасибо!!! Получилось!